# Array of targets for javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am wondering; How do i add an array of targets to this script?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#kategorierbuttons').click(function(e)
{
   var num = $(e.target).index() + 1;
   $('option:nth-child(' + num + ')', '#kategorier_content1').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
});
```

Where '#kategorier_content1' is the target of the function, it's what changes when the function is invoked. I would like to pair (As in, they get changed in the exact same way) more targets into that function, i.e. (Nonfunctioning script only intended to demonstrate the gist of what i want):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#kategorierbuttons').click(function(e)
{
   var num = $(e.target).index() + 1;
   $('option:nth-child(' + num + ')', '#kategorier_content1', '#kategorier_content2').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
});
```

Unfortunately, my knowledge of javascript, which isn't very much, doesn't cover this, and therefore i ask for help. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SEqZG/46/

Aim is to get both dropdown menus to behave the same according to the function, not just the top one.

Comment: Also post (the relevant portion of) your HTML. It's impossible to help you without that.

Comment: What is this doing? Any errors? And does this do? Put your HTML here...

Comment: Is this what you want?: http://jsfiddle.net/SEqZG/47/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want, though i'd preferred an array instead of adding another line. Wasn't there any other way to do it than to add another line in the function?

Comment: Yes wait, I will put another way in as I will answer your question, then you accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be changing both these options for each `click`.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#kategorierbuttons').click(function(e)
    {
        var num = $(e.target).index() + 1;
        $('option:nth-child(' + num + ')', '#kategorier_content1').attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('option:nth-child(' + num + ')', '#kategorier_content2').attr('selected', 'selected'); //One extra line, but what if there are many?
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SEqZG/47/)**

But, what if you have array with elements with id start with your requirement?

Then you will have to select elements using this selector:

```
element_type[attribute^="value"]
```

Read here about it: **[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

Then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#kategorierbuttons').click(function(e)
    {
        var num = $(e.target).index() + 1;
        $('select[id^="kategorier_content"]').find('option:nth-child(' + num + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SEqZG/48/)**

Comment: There actually will be a total of 17 targets, so a line per each isn't preferable, but if there's no other way...

Comment: Yes there is, but tell me if all have `id`s starting with `kategorier_content`?

Comment: Yes, they all start with kategorier_content, though not all have numbers after that, some have more text

Comment: I will give it a go, and let you know if it works, it shouldn't take more than 5-10 minutes

Comment: It works, on both the ones having alphabetical characters after the requirement, and the ones with numerical characters. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, kudos for linking to where i can read more about the solution.

Comment: Yes glad to help, and about all types of selectors, you can read furthur: [**jQuery Selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)